# How to blur text in vim

Tags: vim, jpasswordfield

I have stored plain text password in config file. Is there any way blur or replace password with XXXXX.

when I open config file in vim I want to see

password = XXXXX

Comment: you can en/decrypt the whole file with vim.

Comment: It's a config file. That program would need access to your encryption key to use the file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest and most secure way of obscuring the password in the config file is

## **DON'T PUT A PLAINTEXT PASSWORD IN A FILE**

Any solution otherwise using vim for what you describe will only obscure the password for *you*.  Other people can open/read the file without vim, seeing the password.

If, for some reason, this *is* the use case you want (say, for projecting a presentation, and you are for *some ungodly reason* using a password that the audience could use to exploit something live (**Why the hell are you doing that**), you can write an `autocmd` that will obscure everything after the equals sign.

```
autocmd BufRead * silent! %s/=[^=]*$/=XXXX/
```

But, note that this is only for a presentation: the text is actually rewritten and you would not want to save this file.

Your other choice would be using 7.3's syntax highlighting to mark the text as concealed.

Comment: Well, if you use Vim's built-in encryption, you still might want to avoid that people looking over your shoulder read the decrypted text.

Comment: +1 "Don't put a plaintext password in a file" needed to be said.

Comment: @chepner It's hard to put passwords in a file if you cannot put passwords there. It's fine to put passwords in an encrypted file, IMO

Comment: This is for a config file, which means if it's encrypted, someone (i.e., the program being configured) besides you needs the key to decrypt it.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, with the *conceal* feature introduced in Vim 7.3, you can replace matches with one replacement character. So you could condense the entire password to a single `*`, or replace every character to a `*` (by matching each password character individually).

Concealing is implemented with syntax highlighting. As long as you don't have any existing syntax for your password files, this is just writing a simple `syntax/password.vim` syntax script and doing

```
:setlocal syntax=password
```

Integrating into other syntaxes is more difficult.

See `:help :syn-conceal` for details. This help page also has all the information about writing a syntax. You'll especially need `:help :syn-match`.

The nice thing about conceal is that you can still yank the original password text (e.g. to the clipboard) without revealing it. The `'conceallevel'` and `'concealcursor'` options control that.

#### Simpler alternative

If you just want to avoid other people reading your passwords from over your shoulder, you could define *folds* for all individual login entries (/ paragraphs), start with all folds closed, and only briefly open the single current fold for access.

Comment: I just cannot think of a reasonable usecase to this requirement. `avoid other people reading your passwords from over your shoulder` that could be one. and conceal could be the key +1